# How do I add a custom method to a Ruby library?

Tags: ruby

I'm using the `Restforce` library to do some Salesforce queries. To do the queries, I usually do the following:

```
client = Restforce.new :username => 'user', :password => 'pass', :security_token => 'token', :client_id => 'client_id', :client_secret => 'client_secret'
```

And then call `client.query` to query Salesforce.

I want to create a custom method called `query_with_alises` so that I can call `client.query_with_aliases` to do some custom functionality.

How would I do this without editing the source code of the library itself?

Comment: Open the class and add a new method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just open the class again and add any method you want.

Though the exact meaning is matter of debate, this is called **monkey-patching**. Some consider monkey-patching only overriding/redefining existing methods (which can be kinda dangerous), other consider any kind of opening existing classes and adding anything, even if they are new methods.

In your specific case, you can monkey-patch Client class from Restforce like that:

```
class Restforce::Data::Client
  def query_with_aliases

    # PUT YOUR CODE HERE

  end    
end
```

Every other method inside `Client` will keep existing and functioning and you will only add the `query_with_aliases`.

Answer (score 1):

Monkey-patch some methods - in ruby you can open class again and add some methods,
or use some technique like

```
module MyPatches
  def query_with_aliases
    # code here...
  end
end

TargetClass.send :include, MyPatches
```

Comment: It's important to give the usual warnings: Don't stomp on existing methods or change their behavior, Core libraries especially.